# Computer unable to run any VM. All VMs freeze

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I have a problem with my current PC:

- MSI Z97S SLI Krait Edition Motherboard
- Intel 4790K CPU

Every time I try to run any VM on that PC the VM ends up freezing at some point, requiring me to hard reset the VM to reboot it. This can happen form 30 seconds after booting the VM to 24 hours. It will always hard freeze with no logs to explain such behavior.

I've tried multiple virtualization apps: Windows Hyper-V, VMWare Workstation, Virtualbox. All of them exhibit the same behavior.

Also same behavior whether Intel VT is enabled or disabled in the bios.

Did anyone ever experience such a problem? How can I pinpoint what the problem is?

Thank you,

Comment: Maybe a firmware bug?

Comment: So your host computer doesn't freeze, just the VM itself? Does the VM host application (VMWare workstation, virtualbox, etc) freeze as well or just the VM guest itself? Without logs it's going to be extremely tough to troubleshoot. I know you said the VM doesn't have any logs, but what about the host... anything there?

Comment: Any problems in other programs?  What OS?  Are you able to run Prime95 for at least the same amount of time, no errors?  Have you reinstalled the OS clean?  What other troubleshooting have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager for high level performance issues. Once process identified, check if it's a shared process. If shared, break out into own process. Monitor process in Performance Monitor looking for memory leak. If none, monitor process in Sysinternals Process Monitor checking for access denies. If none, find executable and enable Auditing check for additional errors. Do search for executable in Microsoft support cases, check if latest version...